# Qr-code reader for android

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to make a QR code reader for android app with camera,
read the code form card . if you all have any information to create it please share with me.

Comment: Your application will be only a QRcode reader or it will be a feature of your application ?

Comment: This is not a question for Stack Overflow. SO Is where you go when you have already started developing your QR code reader and run into problems with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below links it will help you,

1)https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView

2)http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-barcode-and-qr-scanner-example/